# Unity Inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I have two classes
First: PlayerPositionSwitchManager
Second: Scrolling Script
When inheriting the variables in the PlayersPositionSwitchManager class, all public variables in the PlayerPositionSwitchManager class appear in the inspector on the ScrollingBgScript class.
[image: FirstClass]

[image: SecondClass]
I do not know why all the first class public variables appear in the second class inspector, and I would not want it. Maybe I do not know yet: D
[image: inspector]

Maybe I'm making some mistakes, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please don't post your code as images. Post it as text.

Comment: Personally, I don't know much about Unity. But having public class variables looks very strange to me.

Comment: @UweKeim, this is how Unity works. They encourage and use this.

Comment: Yes, because unity uses Drag&Drop very much

Comment: @UweKeim - Public class variables exist in Unity so that you can pull GameObjects in the inspector to connect references.

Comment: Strange that they do not support properties.

Comment: Yes, I can refer them to the inspector, but it comes out as a reference twice in the first class that is attached to another object and in this class that is attached to another object

Comment: @UweKeim, they do support properties, but most of the Unity "devs" are too lazy to do that.

Comment: They do not encourage this, that is a misconception. You can have your variables private and just use the [SerializeField] attribute, if you want your variables to show up in Inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want them to show up in the child class, consider using the **protected** access modifier instead of public or decorating them as [HideInInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Attributes.html)

Comment: yes, I do not think I can do what I want by inheritance, I just have to refer to the first class and attach it to the inspector, then I will have access to all the stuff in the first clsa

Comment: hmmm, this was a stupid question, it was clear why references appear in the inspector. I am an idiot :D

Comment: @Geo_Tek - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

In Unity, public variables will always appear in the class inspector. Since your ScrollingBgScript inherits those public variables, then it is as if ScrollingBgScript has access to those public variables. Those variables will inevitably show up in the class inspector. Does this answer your question?